# Error sharing LDAP between WSO2 IS and ESB

Tags: wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I'm a newbie using WSO2 IS 5.0.0 and ESB 4.8.1, trying out this example @ http://hasini-gunasinghe.blogspot.sg/2011/08/fine-grained-authorization-to-restful.html (had changed xacml 2.0 to 3.0 policy, published policy to PDP)
Had also referred to https://malalanayake.wordpress.com/2013/02/13/authentication-and-authorization-with-wso2esb-and-wso2is/

In user-mgmt.xml of ESB, had set AddAdmin to false,
comment the org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager section and uncomment the ISUserStoreManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager" section and restart ESB

However, it is throwing  [Start Level Event Dispatcher] ERROR Activator Cannot start User Manager Core bundle
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.(DefaultRealmService.java:87)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.(DefaultRealmService.java:114)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:69)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

Pls assist. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So,  you want to configure ESB to connect to the LDAP user store of the WSO2IS. Then you want to go through followings.  (Please note ESB does not contain embedded LDAP server.)

1. Comment the `org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager`
2. Uncomment  `ISUserStoreManager`
3. Rename the `ISUserStoreManager` tag in to `UserStoreManager`
4. Configure the LDAP url in to WSO2IS server's LDAP url. You can do it by configuring following property under `UserStoreManager` element.  By default LDAP port of WSO2IS is  `10389`  (with port offset 0)

   `<Property name="ConnectionURL">ldap://localhost:10389</Property>`

Also,  if you are using WSO2IS for XACML authorization,  I would suggest for you to go through [this](http://xacmlinfo.org/) blog as it contain all basic for to work with XACML in WSO2IS.

Comment: After renamed ISUserStoreManager tag to UserStoreManager (had previously changed ldap://localhost:${Ports.EmbeddedLDAP.LDAPServerPort} to ldap://localhost:10389) and restarted ESB. Now it's working. Thanks Asela. Sorry I cannot upvote your answer as I'm too junior.

Comment: Unfortunately this is still relevant for APIM 2.2.0, this helped me however