# error while integrating wso2 API manager and Wso2 identity server

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am integrating WSO2 API manager and WSO2 Identity Server so that Identity Server will be used as key manager.
I followed
https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Configuring+the+Pre-Packaged+Identity+Server+5.2.0+with+API+Manager+2.0.0

But while starting WSO2 Identity Server I am getting below exception,

[2016-12-27 12:28:05,001] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator} -  Cannot start User Manager Core bundle
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.(DefaultRealmService.java:86)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.(DefaultRealmService.java:113)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:68)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

can someone please help?

Comment: how you have configured user store ldap or jdbc user store ? similar stack trace http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27980665/error-sharing-ldap-between-wso2-is-and-esb

Comment: Thanks..I configured the jsbc user store.it works fine.